# trying to send db.collection().find() back to client with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB to get back all of my collections with:

```
rawData = db.collection('Forecasts').find({});
```

After getting the collection I want to return this via res.json() function to the client side. how can i return it.

Adding my Server side code (using Express and Node JS):

```
router.post('/forecastHistory', (req, res, next) => {
  var rawData;
  var forecasts = [];
  // Connection url
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/SimplyForecastDB';
  // Connect using MongoClient
  MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || url, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server.');
    }
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB server.');
    rawData = db.collection('Forecasts').find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, undefined, 2));
      forecasts.push(doc);
    });

    db.close();
  });
  forecasts.forEach(function(doc){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, undefined, 2));
  });
  res.json(forecasts);
});
```

Adding my client side code here to (using js query and ajax):

```
$("#history").click(function() {
  $.post('/forecastHistory', function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(forecast){ 
      $("#forecast").html(
        "<p class=\"lead\">" + forecast.location + "</p>" +
        "The summary of today: " + forecast.summary +
        "<br>" + "Temp: " + forecast.temperature + " C" +
        "<br>" + "It feels like: " + forecast.feelsLike + " C" +
        "<br>" + "The Humidity: " + forecast.humidity + " %" + 
        "<br>" + "Wind Speed: " + forecast.windSpeed + " km/h" +
        "<br>"
      )
    });
  });
});
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Hello , first of all if your request will only  get data from db then you should use get method and not post. Could you console.log result in your client and tell me the result?

Comment: Hi, I need to move the rawData object to the client side, it doesn't work for me in this server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, it seems like you are sending the response to the client before you get the response from MongoDB, thus the 'forecasts' variable would be essentially empty. And since you want to send an array in response, use toArray instead of forEach

```
router.post('/forecastHistory', (req, res, next) => {
var rawData;
var forecasts = [];
// Connection url
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/SimplyForecastDB';
// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || url, (err, db) => {
if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server.');
}
console.log('Connected to MongoDB server.');
rawData = db.collection('Forecasts').find({}).toArray(function(err,doc) {
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
     return;
   }
  res.json(doc);
  res.end();
});

db.close();
});
});
```